# Tab view in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have been trying to use a tab view inside a fragment,but some errors are coming while accessing it through the navigation bar.while accessing it for the first time,i can freely move from tab to tab,but when coming again to this page from another fragment,no longer the tab is moving and i am stucked in a single tab only and by default only the first tab showing.Please help.

Here is my BlankFragment3.java code:

```
public class BlankFragment3 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private MainActivity myContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        myContext= (MainActivity) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment3, container, false);


        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(myContext.getSupportFragmentManager()));
        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabsStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabsStrip.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
        // Attach the view pager to the tab strip
        tabsStrip.setViewPager(viewPager);
        return view;
    }
}
```

here is my fragment.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar">
    </include>

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
        app:pstsTextAllCaps="true"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="#ff9900"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:pstsUnderlineColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp">
    </com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here is the SampleFragmentPagerAdapter.java code:

```
public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Today's Deals", "Deals Close By" };

    public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position==0) {
            return new TodaysDeal();
        } else {
            return new DealsCloseBy();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried fragmenttabhost?

Comment: Have to see the errors at least to know. Maybe also your Activity

Comment: @milez--heres my MainActivity code added above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    private FragmentTabHost tabHost;

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        tabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
        tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.layout.my_parent_fragment);

        Bundle arg1 = new Bundle();
        arg1.putInt("Arg for Frag1", 1);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Tab1")),
                FragmentA.class, arg1);

        Bundle arg2 = new Bundle();
        arg2.putInt("Arg for Frag2", 2);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2")),
            FragmentB.class, arg2);


        return tabHost;

    }
```

XML

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Comment: @Roman--can you please tell me what to write in my_Parent_fragment.xml

Comment: @Roman--Thank u..but still some exception is arrising during rendering..        Exception raised during rendering: No tab known for tag null

Comment: Exception raised during rendering: No tab known for tag nul

Comment: clean your project and run it

Comment: @Roman-its still there ands its appearing before running at the xml preview

Comment: i hope this one helps you more...https://github.com/Balaji-K13/Navigation-drawer-page-sliding-tab-strip

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```