# How can i change fragment on the swipe to left or right menu?

Tags: android, menu

I'm developing an Android App, how can I include change of Fragment, by
scrolling to left or right?

For example like whatsapp, or facebook's fragment in this way:

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout   refer this example@Gigbit

Answer (score 0):

Use Tabview:

refer to below links
[Tab view in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801375/tab-view-in-a-fragment)

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/